# How to find a route in Express?

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using Express and trying to check login credentials, It works fine when i use post request without route. But I am getting error when i use  express route.

This  is my index.js code

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bookworm", { useNewUrlParser: true });

console.log("post request");
app.use("api/auth", auth);

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Running on localhost:8080"));

routes/auth.js code,

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).json({ errors: { global: "Invalid Credentials" } });
});
```

I am expecting, 400:Invalid Credentials. but i am getting 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'global' of undefined"

Comment: Why don't you need all the requests to go through auth middleware?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not letting your `app` know that it has to use `router` in certain endpoints.

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(401).json({ errors: { global: "Invalid Credentials" } });
})

app.use('api', router)
app.listen(8080, () => console.log('listening on 8080'))
```

Now you can call the endpoint like so: `http://localhost:8080/api` with a `POST` request and it should return you a 401 error

More info here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: I have changed the code as you said, But again i am getting same issue.

import express from "express";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(401).json({ errors: { global: "Invalid Credentials" } });
});

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.use("api/auth", router);
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Running on localhost:8080"));

Comment: This is my client side application api.js code,
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  user: {
    login: credentials =>
      axios.post("/api/auth", { credentials }).then(res => res.data.user)
  }
};

Comment: Now I fixed this issue. I forgot to put  / slash in the begining. Now it works perfect.

  app.use("/api/auth", auth);